# Change background on click or send to link

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I basically want for the visitor to be able to click on a picture and for the background to change for page X but for the rest to link to page Y.

I want my WordPress site to say the following :

If page 1 show that code X if else change the  for

HTML

```
<div class="box1">     
 <ul id="bgbg">
   <li id="bg1"><a href="#"></a> </li>
   <li id="bg2"><a href="#"></a> </li>
   <li id="bg3"><a href="#"></a> </li>
```

```
<?php if (is_page ('1')){?> 

<script> 
jQuery(document).ready(function() {     
  jQuery( "#bgbg > li" ).click(function() {      
  jQuery( 'body' ).removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3');      
  jQuery( 'body' ).addClass(jQuery(this).attr('id')) ;   });});
</script>

<?php } else { ?>

<script> 
 ?!??
</script>
```

My attempt :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {     
jQuery("#bgbg a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com");
});

</script>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: you might want to use `window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bgbg > li").click(function() {
    var img_url = $(this).find('img').prop('src');
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + img_url + ')');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1">
  <ul id="bgbg">
    <li id="bg1">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://www.personalizedbottlesofwater.com/img/customers/bmw.jpg"></a>
    </li>
    <li id="bg2">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://www.autreplanete.com/ap-social-media-image-maker/ressources/img/img_format/youtube_avatar_200x200.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li id="bg3">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```